# DLL file for Modbus protocol in windows 7

Tags: dll, modbus, ateasy

I'm looking for a Modbus dll for Windows 7 with his header file.
I need it to create a driver for communicating with a MultiMeter via
Modbus protocol in `ATEasy` environment.

Comment: Did you find the dll driver? Do you have the driver in another launguage (c for example)?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I know a website that can help you.

I hope I have been helpful. :)

Website click [here](http://www.fixerrorhelps.com/fix-pc-error/how-to-fix-MODBUS.DLL-error.html)!